# Top Questions of the Week #4

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into week 4 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://superuser.blogoverflow.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each we week we are going to try to post about the question and it's contents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[How is Linux not prone to viruses, malware and those kinds of things?](https://superuser.com/questions/195387/how-is-linux-not-prone-to-viruses-malware-and-those-kinds-of-things)

> I am unable to figure out, how is linux protected against viruses?
>
> I am no cracker. It was just out of curiosity that I am asking this question.

A simple question with some great answers.